# Reduce stem growth of flowers

Tags: plant-health, plant-care, flowers, stems

I have 2 trough planters with various flowers in thank my kids have planted.

As you can see from the images below, they have grown quite tall and the bottom of the trough where the stems are look a little bare.

For the future, is there any way I can reduce the height of the flowers so they aren’t as tall?

[image: flower trough 1]
[image: flower trough 2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thnk the basic problem is that they are much too crowded together, so they are growing to try to get more light.

Even small flowering plants need to be 8 or 12 inches apart to develop normally to their full size. If you sowed the seeds straight into the container, you need to sow more seeds than that since they won't all germinate, and then thin out the seedlings when they are big enough to see which are the strongest plants.

This is a common beginner's mistake. Tiny plants only an inch across that are spaced a foot apart might look a bit silly until they grow bigger, but that is what will produce the best results in the end.

Comment: Ahh that makes sense. I think my kids just emptied full pack of seeds into them.